# Как оптимизировать процесс выборки информации о скаченых файлах?

Tags: php, mysql, инспекция-кода

Как можно ускорить процесс выборки информации о скачены файлах? На данный момент информация о скаченных файлах лежит в MySQL.

Вот как это выглядит сейчас:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id FROM daemon_zip WHERE dir_city = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $dir_city);
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();
$res = $res->fetch_assoc();

if ($res == null) {
  // ...
}
```

Нужно оптимизировать процесс выборки информации о скаченных файлах и проверки скачен файл или нет, на данным момент проверка скачен файл или нет занимает очень много времени, от `0.1s`

P.S: На данный момент в базе около <s>140 тысяч</s> 8 миллионов  записей.

Comment: Задайте вопрос более развёрнуто

Comment: Нужно оптимизировать процесс хранения информации о скачены файлах и проверки скачен файл или нет, на данным момент проверка скачен файл или нет занимает очень много времени, от 0.3s

Comment: Раз у Вас идет выборка по полю url и делается это я так понимаю достаточно часто, то можно попробовать сделать индекс по этому полю. И смотреть. Может хорошо помочь в поиске.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Храни данные в файле в json формате**.
Чтение (без критeрий:выбрать все) и запись в файл на порядок быстрее.

Или повесь индекс на те колонки по которым идет выборка.На данный момент это колонка `url`.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX `indx_name` (`url`)
```

Всегда пользуйтесь [**подготовленными запросами**.](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

**СУБД MySQL** поддерживает подготавливаемые запросы. Подготавливаемые (или параметризованные) запросы используются для повышения эффективности, когда один запрос выполняется многократно.

- [Использование индексов в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html)
- [Синтаксис оператора CREATE INDEX](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/CREATE_INDEX.html)

Comment: Так у автора поиск, а не чтение-запись тормозит. К тому же, сделав все в json, все равно нужно будет делать свой поиск. Плюс решать вопрос  с блокировкой файла, что бы два процесса не писали одновременно.

Comment: @KoVadim Все равно работа с файлом быстрее.я написал и второй вариант про index.Тут у каждого есть свой плюс и минус.Надо сидеть и проверять оба варианта,И не лениться :)

Comment: боюсь, что Вы так просто не сможете написать быстрее на файлах, чем на базе, если записей будет даже 100к.

Comment: Да использования индекса помогло и использовать файл не очень подходит